# IBrokers - How I send 100000 to IBrokers:::.placeOrder?

Tags: java, r, ibrokers

I'm using IBrokers to open orders for AUD-USD on IDEALPRO

Here is syntax which works well for me to SELL 90,000:

```
# myscript.r

.libPaths("rpackages")
library(IBrokers)
myconid = 3
twsobj  = twsConnect(myconid)
myaud = twsCurrency("AUD",currency="USD",exch="IDEALPRO",primary="",strike="0.0",right="",local="",multiplier="",include_expired="0",conId=myconid)
Sys.sleep(2)
myorderid = as.integer(reqIds(twsobj))
print(myorderid)
Sys.sleep(2)
myorderid = as.integer(difftime(Sys.time(), "2014-10-30", units = "secs"))
Sys.sleep(2)
IBrokers:::.placeOrder(twsobj, myaud, twsOrder(myorderid,"SELL", 90000, "MKT"))
Sys.sleep(4)
twsDisconnect(twsobj)
```

Next, I try to place an order for 100,000 with this API call:

```
IBrokers:::.placeOrder(twsobj, myaud, twsOrder(myorderid,"SELL", 100000, "MKT"))
```

The order fails.

I see this in my log:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1e+05"
```

A simple workaround is to place 2 orders for 50000.

I'm looking for clues on other workarounds.

I suspect that the bug is that IBrokers is sending 1e+05 to the API instead of 100000.

Comment: I just found the answer via google 'disable scientific notation in R'. The answer is, I insert this line of syntax before I make the call  `options("scipen"=4)`  I will answer correctly once SO allows me.

Comment: Try passing a string instead of a number.  i.e. `"100000"` instead of `100000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# myscript.r

.libPaths("rpackages")
library(IBrokers)
myconid = 3
twsobj  = twsConnect(myconid)
myaud = twsCurrency("AUD",currency="USD",exch="IDEALPRO",primary="",strike="0.0",right="",local="",multiplier="",include_expired="0",conId=myconid)
Sys.sleep(2)
myorderid = as.integer(reqIds(twsobj))
print(myorderid)
Sys.sleep(2)
myorderid = as.integer(difftime(Sys.time(), "2014-10-30", units = "secs"))
Sys.sleep(2)

# my workaround:
options("scipen"=4)

IBrokers:::.placeOrder(twsobj, myaud, twsOrder(myorderid,"SELL", 190000, "MKT"))
Sys.sleep(4)
twsDisconnect(twsobj)
```